# Is it possible for matter to occupy a singularity, which is the point of rupture of space time caused by a black hole?

Tags: singularities, dark-energy, reversibility, matter

Also, are singularities caused by blackholes reversible? May one do work to reverse the singularity or black hole? Do blackholes create permanent holes in space time, thereby shrinking space time, or is the area of space time constant, and every time a black hole punctures space time space time expands via dark energy in every other direction to maintain a constant surface area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not reversible. Black holes eventually evaporate, but this takes longer than the decay of the universe, it is unknown what comes after. Space time may either be seen as stretching or expanding, though one may assume that what is accreted into a super-dense object will make the whole around it less voluminous though they are part of the same fabric essentially. It depends on what metric you refer to as shrinking. I would assume not as they grow in size so the surface area is already expanding. I have recently heard that Quasars or Black holes may be our universes way of dealing with entropy while essentially dropping off a seed for another universe. This ensures the universe survives even as it evaporates itself, or 'accrues' matter, and accounts for Einsteins white hole.

Comment: Was our universe originated from a quasar?

Comment: May we enter a quasar to survive our universe’s heat death?